# PHP define class with namespace

Tags: php, namespace, define

```
namespace A\B\C\D\E\F\G;

class H {
  public static function i($a) {
    return $a * 2;
  }
}

print_r(A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H::get());
```

Как заменить во всех областях видимости и пространствах имен A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H на просто Н?
Чтобы вызывать отовсюду

```
print_r(H::get());
```

Так не работает:

```
define("H", "A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H");
H::get(2);
```

Comment: `use My\Full\Classname as Another;` https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: Это работает только после namespace Класса - глобально не работает

Answer (score 1):

Если понимаете, что вы по сути делаете костыль, но все равно хотите его создать, то пишите

```
(H)::get(2)
```

в противном случае ищется класс `H` а не константа `H`. При этом, если делать сие в одном файле, то будет работать.

```
<?php

namespace A\B\C\D\E\F\G;

define('H', H::class);

class H {
    public static function get(int $id){
        echo $id;
    }
}
```

и вызывающий

```
<?php
  require_once "h.class.php";

  (H)::get(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Укажите явно, что вы хотите использовать класс из нужного пространства:

```
use A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H;
H::get(2);
```

[Ссылка на документацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: лень ему просто писать `use`, хочет костыль

Comment: @teran возможно, он просто не знает про импорт/алиасы для пространств имён

Comment: возможно, но странно знать про `namespace` и не знать про `use`